# Processing loading table data

Tags: file-upload, datatable, processing

I have a text file "celldata.txt" containing a very simple table of data.

1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
9 10 11 12
1 2 3 4
2 3 4 5

The problem is when it comes to accessing the data at a certain column and row.
My approach has been to load using loadTable.

```
Table table;
int numCols;
int numRows;

void setup() {
 size(200,200);
 table = loadTable("celldata.txt","tsv");
 numRows=table.getRowCount();
 numCols=table.getColumnCount();

}

void draw() {
 background(255);
 fill(0);
 text(numRows +" "+ numCols,100,100);  // Check num of cols and rows
 println(table.getFloat(0,0));
}
```

Question 1: When I do this, it says the number of rows are 5 and the number of columns is just 1. Why is it not 5 x 4?

Question 2: Why is table.getFloat(0,0) "NaN" instead of the first element of the data?

I want to use a much bigger matrix later and access certain elements (of type double) with something like getFloat(i,j) and be able to loop through all elements.
Using the same example data as I, can someone please help me understand what is wrong with my code and how to access the textfile's data? Should I be using another method than loadTable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've told Processing that the file contains **tab separated values** (by using the `"tsv"` option), but your file contains **space separated values**.

Since your file does not contain any tabs, it reads the entire row as a single value. So the `0,0` position of your table is `1 2 3 4`, which isn't a number- hence the `NaN`. This is also why it thinks your table only has one column.

You should modify your `celldata.txt` file to actually be separated by tabs instead of spaces:

```
1   2   3   4
5   6   7   8
9   10  11  12
1   2   3   4
2   3   4   5
```

You could also separate them by commas and then use the `"csv"` option.

If you're still having trouble, you can see what Processing is reading in by adding `saveTable(table, "data/new.csv");` to the end of your `setup()` function and then looking at that file. It will be a list of values separated by commas, so you can see exactly where Processing thinks the cells of the table are.